# How do I find the form of a wave equation given initial conditions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

This is probably trivial, but I'm having trouble finding the correct solution given the data I have, and the general solutions to the classical wave equation I know. In essence, I'm being asked to find $\Psi(x,t)$ knowing:

$$\Psi(x,0)=he^{-x^2/2a^2}\\ \dot{\Psi}(x,0)=0$$

The solution being: $\Psi(x,t)=\frac{h}{2}\left(e^{-(x-vt)^2/2a^2} + e^{-(x+vt)^2/2a^2} \right)$ which is obviously correct. Now, solutions to the wave equation can be written in terms that depend on $e^{i(kx+wt)},e^{-i(kx+wt)}$, etc. Now, I can see that perhaps one could write $\Psi(x,0)=he^{(ix/\sqrt{2}a)^2}$ to get the imaginary units, but where does the square come from? How is this a solution to the wave equation, and how do you find it generally without just guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to solve the wave equation. One, as you note, is to use  a Fourier transform and get solutions as a sum of harmonics $e^{-(kx - \omega t)}$.

When you have initial conditions as shown, the easier method is [d'Alembert's solution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html). This immediately yields the solution given, as (following the notation in the linked article)
$$
y_0(x) = he^{-\frac {x^2}{2a^2}}
$$
$$
v_0(x) = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of these.